# Error when trying to add firebase libraries to app that uses google maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android app that I want to add firebase messaging service functionality so I can receieve notifications that are sent from my self-built server to the firebase cloud.

I started adding the configuration lines to the gradle files, but after adding the

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

line, I get an error as follows:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.2.

This is my module:app gradle script file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.berait.brecar"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.2'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.7'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

if needed, this is my project level gradle script file:

```
//Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have searched S.O for sometime now and all the answers to this type of error haven't worked for me. As you can see, i have the apply plugin line at the bottom of the file. I believe the conflict is being generated by the

> ```
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
> ```

line, which was automatically added when I added google maps API support to my application.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bump up the firebase dependency version to

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
```

or lower the maps dependency to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I knew it was something simple as that